# function to return all S3 methods applicable to an object

Tags: r, r-s3

Has anyone put together/found a good method for listing all the **S3** methods available for a given *object*?  The built-in `methods()` function will give all available methods for a specified class, or for a specified generic function, but not for an object.

The example I have in mind is a `glm` object, which is of (minor?) class `"glm"` but also inherits from `"lm"`

```
g <- glm(y~x,data=data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10))
class(g)
## [1] "glm" "lm"
```

There are 35 methods for class "lm" and 22 for "glm".  I'm interested in an answer that combines the results of

```
lapply(class(g),function(x) methods(class=x))
```

in a sensible way, so that I can immediately see (for example) that there is a `glm`-specific method for `add1`, but that the method for `alias` is inherited from the `lm` class.

Does someone have a slick way to do this, or does it already exist?

PS Steve Walker's [S3-S4-reference class glossary](http://stevencarlislewalker.wordpress.com/s3-s4-dictionary/) shows that this works automatically for reference classes, where we have to use an object to get the methods (`x$getRefClass()$methods()`).

Comment: It's a little misleading to ask for the methods of an S3 class, since in S3 it's functions that have methods, not classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an attempt to replicate the "standard" behavior

```
classMethods <- function(cl) {
    if(!is.character(cl)) {
        cl<-class(cl)
    }
    ml<-lapply(cl, function(x) {
        sname <- gsub("([.[])", "\\\\\\1", paste0(".", x, "$"))
        m <- methods(class=x)
        data.frame(
            m=as.vector(m), 
            c=x, n=sub(sname, "", as.vector(m)),
            attr(m,"info"),
            stringsAsFactors=F
        )
    })
    df<-do.call(rbind, ml)
    df<-df[!duplicated(df$n),]
    structure(df$m, 
        info=data.frame(visible=df$visible, from=df$from), 
        class="MethodsFunction")
}
```

And then you can try it out with

```
g <- glm(y~x,data=data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10))
classMethods(g)
#or classMethods(c("glm","lm"))
```

and that will return

```
 [1] add1.glm*           anova.glm           confint.glm*        cooks.distance.glm*
 [5] deviance.glm*       drop1.glm*          effects.glm*        extractAIC.glm*    
 [9] family.glm*         formula.glm*        influence.glm*      logLik.glm*        
[13] model.frame.glm     nobs.glm*           predict.glm         print.glm          
[17] residuals.glm       rstandard.glm       rstudent.glm        summary.glm        
[21] vcov.glm*           weights.glm*        alias.lm*           case.names.lm*     
[25] dfbeta.lm*          dfbetas.lm*         dummy.coef.lm*      hatvalues.lm       
[29] kappa.lm            labels.lm*          model.matrix.lm     plot.lm            
[33] proj.lm*            qr.lm*              simulate.lm*        variable.names.lm* 

   Non-visible functions are asterisked
```

It's not as elegant or short as Josh's, but I think its a good recreation of the default behavior. It's funny to see that the `methods` function is itself mostly just a grep across all known function names. I borrowed the `gsub` stuff from there.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a function that will at least tell you which S3 methods an object will initially trigger:

```
findMethodsS3 <- function(object) {
    x <- unlist(lapply(class(object),function(x) methods(class=x)))   
    sort(x[!duplicated(tools::file_path_sans_ext(x))])
}

findMethodsS3(g)
#  [1] "add1.glm"           "alias.lm"           "anova.glm"         
#  [4] "case.names.lm"      "confint.glm"        "cooks.distance.glm"
#  [7] "deviance.glm"       "dfbeta.lm"          "dfbetas.lm"        
# [10] "drop1.glm"          "dummy.coef.lm"      "effects.glm"       
# [13] "extractAIC.glm"     "family.glm"         "formula.glm"       
# [16] "hatvalues.lm"       "influence.glm"      "kappa.lm"          
# [19] "labels.lm"          "logLik.glm"         "model.frame.glm"   
# [22] "model.matrix.lm"    "nobs.glm"           "plot.lm"           
# [25] "predict.glm"        "print.glm"          "proj.lm"           
# [28] "qr.lm"              "residuals.glm"      "rstandard.glm"     
# [31] "rstudent.glm"       "simulate.lm"        "summary.glm"       
# [34] "variable.names.lm"  "vcov.glm"           "weights.glm"
```

Comment: It's the easiest-to-remember complicated name for an R function that I know of. Remembering whether it's in `utils` or `tools` is what usually gets me...

Comment: That only works as long as the class name doesn't have a "." in it, right?

Comment: looks like it should work: `tools::file_path_sans_ext("a.b.c")` is `"a.b"`

Comment: @MrFlick -- Yes, very good point. Looks like the only solution is to explicitly strip off the known class names, as your function does.

Comment: @BenBolker I was thinking more like `tools::file_path_sans_ext("print.data.frame")=="print.data"`