# R: Is there any way to find R functions which are tests of objects of a specified class?

Tags: r, class, generics, search, methods

There are a number of tests which, applied to an object of a given class, produce information about that object. Consider objects of class "function". The functions `is.primitive()` or `is.closure()`, or  (from rlang) `is_primitive_eager()` or `is_primitive_lazy()`, provide information about a function object. However, Using `methods(class = "function"`) (with rlang loaded) does not return any of these functions:

`[1] as.data.frame as.list coerce coerce<- fortify head latex plot print  tail` .

Using `extends(class1 = "function", maybe = TRUE, fullInfo = TRUE)` shows two superclasses,  "OptionalFunction" and "PossibleMethod".
Using `completeClassDefinition(Class = "function", doExtends=TRUE)` provides 23 subclasses. However, it appears to me (though I am not sure of this)  that all or almost all of the super- and sub-classes from these two functions are specifically of S4 classes, which I generally do not use.  One of these subclasses is "genericFunction", so I tried to apply it to a base R function which I knew to be generic. Although `is(object=plot,  class2 = "genericFunction")` returns TRUE, and `plot()` antedates S4 classes, there is no "is.generic" test in base R, but there is an "isGeneric" test in the methods package, which suggests to me that `plot()` has been rewritten as an S4 object.

At any rate, there are a lot of obvious potential properties of functions, like whether they are generic, for which there are no `is.<whatever>` tests that I can find, and I would like to know if there are other ways I can search for them, e.g., in packages.

A more generic way of asking this same question is whether there is any way of identifying functions that will accept objects of a specified class and not return an error or nonsense. If so I could take a list of the functions in the reccomended packages or in some specified package and test whether each returns a sensable response when handed a function. This is not exactly an answer --- such a method would return TRUE for quote(), for example -- but it would at least cut the problem down to size.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23840714/2994949